# Cannot call api route from client app loaded by distant browser

Tags: api, vue.js, express, axios, localhost

I have a server where there is an api running on port 8081 and a client Vue app running on 8082.

My client app using Axios to make queries to the api using the following code.

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/route',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  },
});
```

The client is served by the following express server :

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const path = __dirname + '/dist/';

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path));

app.use(cors());

app.get('*', function (req,res) {
  res.sendFile(path + "index.html");
});

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = 8082;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

If I use my app directly from the server there is no problem, the query is correctly executed.

But if I load the app from a distant browser, the client is not capable to execute the query, trying to use the 127.0.0.1 of the distant browser, not the server one.

[Error case with browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnAIy.png)

Setting Axios to use the local IP of the server make the things work but the application need to be generic and it should only use the 127.0.0.1 because the app and api will always be on the same machine.

Comment: What you are saying is contradictory. _"because the app and api will always be on the same machine"_ - but that is obviously _not_ the case in the error scenario you just described to us.

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear. The Vue app is running on the same server than the the API.
Now I want to access from my browser's computer remotely to the Vue app, using the server address. But queries to the api does not work in this use case.

Comment: The request happens in the browser. So there is no way for `127.0.0.1` to point to the _other_ machine you want it to.

Comment: Yeah of course but I meant to interpret 127.0.0.1 as the local machine IP which is impossible. Btw I found my solution switching 127.0.0.1 to the global variable 'window.location.hostname', it makes the configuration generic and i don't need to specify in the code the address of the server. I can now use one code to multiple servers without any configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, to make the address generic, I need to use the global variable:

```
window.location.hostname
```

That contains the hostname of the machine that runs the Vue app server.

Now when I try to make a request from distant computer, my browser is correctly using the machine hostname, not its own localhost.

This is the new Axios configuration :

```
const apo = axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://${window.location.hostname}:8081/api/route`,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  },
});
```